# How to get year , month, date from days in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Given a number as 269 or 456.. how can I get the year, month and days using a single line sql function.. if possible?

Thanks

Comment: What is the link between 269 and 09 Dec 2010 please?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 0, 456)
```

OK, seriously how about

```
SELECT  DATEADD(day, 0, 456) DateVal,
        DATEDIFF(year,0,DATEADD(day, 0, 456)) YearPart,
        DATEPART(month,DATEADD(day, 0, 456)) MonthPart,
        DATENAME(month,DATEADD(day, 0, 456)) MonthNamePart,
        DATEPART(day,DATEADD(day, 0, 456)) DayPart
```

Output

```
DateVal                 YearPart    MonthPart   MonthNamePart   DayPart
1901-04-02 00:00:00.000 1           4           April           2
```

Comment: But the sysntax is DATEADD (datepart , number , date ) ..so the last part should be date right and not a number.. well I donot have sql server at present to verify.. I will check it later